# hide domain user on windows logon screen

Tags: windows, active-directory

At the moment, I'm preventing our admin account from showing on the logon screen using this registry.

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon\SpecialAccounts\UserList]
```

However this seems to only hide local accounts. How can I hide a domain based account? I tried adding `domain\domainAdminUser` and `domainAdminUser` which both did not work.

I don't want to hide the all logged on accounts. Just the specified account.

Comment: Why would those accounts even show?  The setting that comes to mind is a GPO in the path: "Computer Configuration\Policies\Windows Settings\Security Settings\Local Policies\Security Options\Interactive logon: Do not display last user name"  I mean, that hides all recenly logged on accounts, but that's the setting that should probably be used.

Comment: @Semicolon I don't want to hide the all logged on accounts. Just the specified account.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this? I am curious, we are likely going to implement the 'do not display last username' security option but if we could impact the userbase less by specifying the admin account(s) that we are really trying to prevent people from accidentally locking out... It would be nice.

Comment: @Jeremy I did not ): It's worth noting that in my setup, I don't have access to the domain side of things. Just campus hierarchy things.